How to build a confirm() like function for NodeJS?
In the browser we have confirm() function which allows to provide a prompt string, and it returns either true/false.
I am trying to create a similar function for a NodeJS cli app. Below I am using readline module. Here is my code:
const readline = require('node:readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});

let q = "Do you agree?";

function confirm(question) {
    let options = ["yes", "y", "YES", "Y"];
    let response;

    rl.question(question, ans => {
      response = ans;
      console.log(`You responded with: ${ans}!`);
      rl.close();
    });

    return options.includes(response);
    
}

let ans1 = confirm(q);
console.log(`ans1=${ans1}`);

let ans2 = confirm(q);
console.log(`ans2=${ans2}`);


For some reason it doesn't work and the output generated is out of order also.
Do you agree?ans1=false
Do you agree?ans2=false
yes
You responded with: yes!

I suspect there is some async behaviour happening as we can see both prompt appear before readline callback is actually called.
How can I fix this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

@tuxdna you can use readline/promises instead

You can use readline/promises to achive that.
const readline = require('node:readline/promises');

const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});

let q = "Do you agree?";

async function confirm(question) {
    let options = ["yes", "y", "YES", "Y"];
    
    let response = await rl.question(question);

    return options.includes(response);
}

async function isAgreed(){
    let ans1 = await confirm(q);
    console.log(`ans1=${ans1}`);

    let ans2 = await confirm(q);
    console.log(`ans2=${ans2}`);

    rl.close()
}

isAgreed()

